# Hadoop: to train large data(in GB) with multiple tree(sampling say N, for say x RandomTree) and test

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning, classification, weka

I want to write MapReduce (may be multiple rounds!) to

```
1. Sample N records from Large data - for say X RandomTree
2. Train each tree (totally X)
3. And then test records on all these trees
```

Sequentially,

```
for X = 0 to 199:
    - sample N records from Large data
    - Train this tree
    - test for all test records
```

This is my homework problem, so I just need idea ..!

I'm not sure with

1. In mapper can I sample exactly N records and generate 200 small
   training data file?
2. To test each record on all 200 *first option*
   I thought of each reducer will run small test (part of test file)
   for ALL trees. *second option* I'm not sure, how to implement this
   is, run 200 tree independently and test file is in Distributed
   cache, predict for each test record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how formal you work.

A *formal* mapper cannot sample exactly N records. Because it cannot keep a counter, and it doesn't know the total data size. A *practical* mapper in Hadoop certainly could. But he probably won't know how many records he is going to receive in total.

But as you said this is a homework, I don't think you need to ensure it is exactly N.
In particular, as you are sampling, what is the benefit of having exactly N records?

Try the following:

1. Determine the total size of records.
2. Have each mapper emit each record with a likelihood of N/D to each tree (= key for reducer).
3. Let the reducer train the tree on all the records it received.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse, I know N too (this is to make sure, it can keep N records in Single Random tree without heap size err) 1. I know size (M) records. 2. You are right, I need to emit with (N/M). that's what I don't know. so each mapper will get some record (from that Large  data) and how to decide that (N/M) probability to be in (0-199) Random tree? It would be great, if you can explain in some more detail. 3. I think thats good way, as I'm not sure, if I can write 200 small sample files in one map-reduce job and give it to next map-reduce job.

Comment: Draw pseudo-random numbers for each object and tree. If the value is below N/M, it's in. otherwise it's out. Pseudo-random is faster than random; you don't want your cluster to be mostly busy with making up random numbers.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Anony-Mousee, but I need 200 random tree, in and out, isnt that just for two?

Comment: For each object, and *each* tree, you need a random. The object can go into any combination of trees, including all or none.

Comment: well actually I need to create uniformly without replacement, I didn't get how is that possible with what you suggested? to make it more clear, from all M total records, I need to sample around N for each tree (total there are 200 trees)

Comment: You process one instance at a time. What is the chance that the instance belongs into the first tree? How can you do this using a random number in 0..1? It's a *lot* easier than you apparently think. I'm not *drawing* from a sample. I'm filtering with a probabilistic filter.

Comment: it belongs to first tree if I get random num < N/M, is that correct?

Comment: May be I'm over-thinking it ... but I seriously don't understand probabilistic filtering!! I did for heads or tails with probability x, but here its 200, and that's what it make me sooooo confused :(((

Comment: Do one tree at a time. You do want them to be independently sampled. So you need for each instance 200 random numbers. Which is why you need a fast pseudo random generator. It doesn't need to be high quality, it mostly just shouldn't produce patterns that are in your data.

Comment: I assume you are doing 0 to n/m, n/m to 2n/m, 2n/m to 3n/m then? Don't. Because that guarantees that your trees are trained on disjoint data, which you usually don't want to enforce. You do want to have a chance for overlap. And you want to be able to increase the number of trees or sample size if necessary to the point where they must be able to overlap.

Comment: what I'm doing is sampling a record, taking a record and get its probability to belong to one tree (for i = 0 to 199 get its probability to be in ith tree, yes if <N/M, and that tree didn't get its N record in total)